# Unable To find the correct xpath for a website in python

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am trying to get the data from https://www.reuters.com/markets/companies/AALI.JK/key-metrics/per-share-data
for data of the `EPS Normalized (Annual)    1,010.14` in xpath.
[Kindly click for the inspect screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUppR.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnFrN.png
From inspect, I use xpath as below but return `['1,833.60', '741.35', '113.12', '1,702.00', '1.0498', '1.2223', '0.0074', '0.1489', '3.231', '1.667', '-0.029', '2.493', '-0.007', '0.42 ', '+0.195', '3,674.84', '3,438.46', '7,016.25', '25,963.00']` which is not the correct data.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page= requests.get('https://www.reuters.com/markets/companies/AALI.JK/key-metrics/per-share-data')
data = html.fromstring(page.content)
data.xpath('//td/span/text()')
```

How may I get `EPS Normalized (Annual)  1,010.14` in a robust code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site uses JavaScript to load its content,

so if you're going to use selenium you can use this

Search for the `th` tag with the text "EPS Basic Excl. Extra Items (Annual)" then get the parent `/..` and you get the rest

`//th[contains(text(), "EPS Basic Excl. Extra Items (Annual)")]/../td/span`

---

if not and want to work with requests, here is a temporary solution

```
import requests, re
from lxml import html

page = requests.get('https://www.reuters.com/markets/companies/AALI.JK/key-metrics/per-share-data')

data = html.fromstring(page.content)

txt = data.xpath('//*[@id="fusion-metadata"]/text()')[0]

eps_norm_annual = float(re.search('"eps_normalized_annual":"([0-9.]+)"', txt).group(1))
```

Comment: Since it is loaded in JS, is that mean the website call an API to get the data?

Comment: @behappy most of the time, yes. but in this case the data are loaded inside the HTML page as a `script` tag in a json format.

Comment: Is there a way to find which link it is loaded?

Comment: @behappy yes I usually open the dev-tools from my browser in the network tab then reload and search for the value I want, in this case, I searched for `1010.14` which is "EPS Normalized (Annual)" and found that it exists within a Javascript variable so i created this regex to capture it.

Comment: Is this link loaded from a API? I was previously using an API from the site but can't find after the url changed

Comment: Could take a look on this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72703354/unable-to-get-json-data-after-a-word-is-match-with-regex Really appreciated

Comment: @behappy sure, I got it.